# Google code scanner not launching the camera to scan qr code

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I tried to use Google code scanner to scan QR code
I added all the dependencies mentioned in the documentation(https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/code-scanner), when I tried to launch the qr scanner, it doesn't launch and throw the below error
`win=Window{1cf822b u0 /com.google.mlkit.vision.codescanner.internal.GmsBarcodeScanningDelegateActivity} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true cleanupOnResume=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=4 caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6533 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:6514 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:6578 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:7166 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:258 android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:613 com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:136`

Code :

```
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Button(onClick = {
        
        val options = GmsBarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(
                Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
                Barcode.FORMAT_AZTEC)
            .build()

        val scanner = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(context, options)
        scanner.startScan()
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcode ->
                // Task completed successfully
            }
            .addOnCanceledListener {
                // Task canceled
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                // Task failed with an exception
            }

    }) {
        Text(text = "Click to Scan")
    }
}
```